# batch pick random file that contains utf-8 characters in its name

Tags: batch-file, utf-8

I want to open a random file in a directory and its subdirectorys with batch. And I know there are enough questions on stackoverflow who give the code for that but none of which I found were with utf-8 character support.

I use the following code which I found in stackoverflow.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"

:: Count the files
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N

call :openRandomFile

:: Delete the temp file
del "%tempFile%"

exit /b

:openRandomFile
set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr "^%randomNum%:" "%tempFile%"'
) do start "" "%%B"
cmd /k
```

It works fine that way, until it picks a file like "blablabla_空色デイズ.mp3", in that case it gives an error like "file blablabla_?????.mp3 could not be found." and I have dozens of these files.

I have tried using `chcp 65001` on the start of the file for using utf-8 and if I did so, the teporary created .txt list shows the correct names of japanese files, but the pick up itself does not work anymore after that, so I took away `@echo off` and cmd prints an error on `set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"`: Error: division by zero.

And at this point, I dont understand anymore whats going on, because the file is working great without `chcp 65001`.
I don't know batch, please, does anyone have an idea how to make it run?
I would be really happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a lot of problems with `findstr` and command output when utf8/unicode characters are involved. In this type of scenarios it is safer (but slower) to avoid them

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    rem %1 = folder where to start to list files 
    rem      if empty, current active directory is used

    rem %2 = file mask
    rem      if empty * is used

    rem What to search
    set "fileMask=%~2" & if not defined fileMask set "fileMask=*"

    rem Retrieve the number of matching files
    set "nFiles=0" & for /r "%~f1." %%a in ("%fileMask%") do set /a "nFiles+=1"
    if %nFiles% lss 1 exit /b

    rem Select a random file 
    set /a "n=(%random% %% nFiles) + 1"
    echo Selected file = %n% / %nFiles%

    rem Count up to the selected file and start it
    2>nul (
        for /r "%~f1." %%a in ("%fileMask%") do (
             set /a "n-=1", "1/n" || ( start "" "%%~fa" & goto :done )
        )
    )
:done
```

That is, count the number of files, select one of them and then start iterating over the list of files decrementing the number of the selected file. When it is `0` (we have reached the selected file), the `1/n` division will fail and the conditional execution operator will execute the `start` command.

Comment: I sat here since yesterday and this finally works with all names, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
) do start "" "%%~sB"
```

in the `:openRandomFile` procedure, which should open the file using its short name.

Sorry - can't test it as I don't have any UTF-8 filenames (that I know about)

Comment: Hmm, sorry but the file doesn't get to do that command, it fails at `set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"`. Tried it anyway, but id didn't work.

Comment: That would probably indicate that `cnt` is being set to 0. In your description, you say `It works fine that way, until it picks a file like...`  so restore the condition that was giving you **that** error and modify the `start` as indicated since it appears that the error you originally reported would be generated from that line.

Comment: Did that too, but then it does not recognize the (japanese) names anymore. Why is `cnt` normally ok and in `chcp 65001` not? Tried nearly everything, but it does not work.